# How to create a persistent live USB Stick for xubuntu 20.4 on macOSMojave 10.14.6

Tags: usb, macos, xubuntu

How can I create a persistent live USB Stick for xubuntu 20.4 on a mac?

I tried following attempt: https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-boot-a-linux-live-usb-stick-on-your-mac/
until the balenaEtcher part, but it is not persistent because as soon as I restart ubunto all changes are gone.

To fix this I tried https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-add-persistence-to-a-live-Kali-Linux-USB-drive-on-Mac
but I couldn't get past the 2nd step

> in terminal, type fdisk /dev/sdb (use YOUR correct path here)

I got this in the terminal and couldn't proceed.

> fdisk: cannot open /dev/loop0: Permission denied

> fdisk: cannot open /dev/sda: Permission denied

> fdisk: cannot open /dev/sdb: Permission denied

I tried also this attempt:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mDRbTHCoj8U
where I got stuck on the mac Linux USB Loader writing the iso file on the USB Stick. The program just got stuck and looked also quit different than on the video (it's 5 years old, that might be why).

My USB Stick has the size of 32 Gb in case it's relevant. The computer I use is a MacBook Air (11 Inch, Mid 2012), macOSMojave 10.14.6.

Answer (score 0):

Just try to boot from one stick and in the installer, install on the second one, and use that as your harddrive to boot from.

Make an image bootable initially (for being able to use the installer):
dd if=/path/to/your/image_xubuntu_x64.img of=/path/to/your/usbstick_to_boot_from

Comment: That I would do but I only have one USB Stick at hand.

Comment: @sunjulie Have you tried partitioning your USB, and installing on the first, while the installer is on the second?

Comment: That's what I have problems with on the mac. When I use Etcher, I can only choose the whole USB Stick and not a partition on it